# Eclipse nexus 5 set Location

Tags: android, eclipse, location, ddms, nexus-5

as the title suggests, developing into a nexus 5 I can not send the coordinates via DDMS. throughout that area tick off.
I've never had this problem with other devices.
In addition, on the settings of phone I put the check mark for "mock locations"

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're debugging your application in a real device you can't send mock locations using Eclipse's DDMS, you need to download an app that emulates mock locations.

Comment: it's wrong. On other device, i can set location from ddms, the problem is only with nexus 5. I solved with fake gps

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an answer.
I solved with an app called "fake GPS"
free on the store.